# How to have ball bounce off paddle in right directions not as a straight line

Tags: javascript, canvas

Forgive my complete noobness here as very new to JS.
I've created a really simple canvas with one rectangle being controlled by keydownevents and one just moving around the canvas in rAF.

I want to now have if the moving ball hits the users rectangle to collide and bounce back but to bounce at the right angle that it hits not just in reverse like i have tried and failed at.

I know i need to calculate where it hits on the users rect, but I have no idea where to start or how
Can someone point me in the right direction or give me a small snippet of what to do?

I'll leave out the Keycode functions for space as they're not needed.

```
function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvasdemo");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    canvasHeight = canvas.height;

    drawSquare();
}

function drawSquare() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  // user controlled square
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
  requestAnimationFrame(drawSquare); 


  if (rect.x + rect.vx > canvasWidth - 20 || rect.x + rect.vx < 0)
    rect.vx = -rect.vx;
  if (rect.y + rect.vy > canvasHeight - 20 || rect.y + rect.vy < 0)
    rect.vy = -rect.vy;

  rect.x += rect.vx;  
  rect.y += rect.vy;   

  // Moving Square 1 (left-right):

  requestAnimationFrame(squareTwo);

   if (dir1 == "right") {
      if (xpos < canvasWidth - 35) {
        xpos += 2;
      }else{
        dir1 = "left";
      }
    }

    if (dir1 == "left") {
      if (xpos>0) {
        xpos -= 2;
      }else{
        dir1 = "right";
      }
   }
}
// Second square
 function squareTwo() {

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(xpos, ypos, 35, 35);
    ctx.fill();    
}
```

Comment: A true bounce off a non-moving paddle requires calculating the angle of incidence that the ball hits the paddle and having it bounce off at the same, but reflected angle.  If you want to influence the angle based on the speed or direction the paddle is moving, then that gets a lot more complicated and more detailed physics will be involved.

Comment: Where is rect defined? What is the width and height of your canvas?

Comment: What is working and what is not? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Ok jfriend00 what would the basics be for if the paddle was static before going into moving paddle?

I left variables out Shashank to save space, Everything is defined as global variables outside of the main function. 
var rect = {
  x: 250,
  y: 140,
  w: 20,
  h: 20,
  vx: 0,
  vy: 0
};

canvas w = 550, h = 300

Comment: Sander my question was how do i get a moving ball to bounce off a paddle at the correct angles while the padding is a)static and the b) moving with user control

Comment: It's trigonometry.  You have to calculate the angle between the moving ball and the face of the paddle and use that angle to set the ball in motion at the same angle after the bounce.  See this [article on reflection](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refln/Lesson-1/The-Law-of-Reflection) off a surface which works the same way.  Also, we don't get notifications of your comments unless you put @username in your comment so most are likely not to notice.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00 i understand that, that article is a good help! i know basic trig. I'm just not sure how to write it in JS for the reflection.

Comment: Actually, it may be simpler than that.  If your velocity is determined by `rect.vx` and `rect.vy` and your paddle is horizontal, then all you have to do is: `rect.vy = -rect.vy;` and that will reverse the y direction but keep the x velocity the same which is how a reflection off a surface parallel to the X axis works.

Answer (score 7):

**To calculate the reflection you can do -**

First, define the normal as a vector based on the pads angle:

```
function getNormal(a) {
    return {
        x: Math.sin(a),    // this will be 90° offset from the
        y: -Math.cos(a)    // incoming angle
    }
}
```

Then use dot-product to calculate the incident angle with the incoming vector:

```
function reflect(n, v) {
    var d = 2 * dot(v, n);   // calc dot product x 2
    v.x -= d * n.x;          // update vectors reflected by
    v.y -= d * n.y;          // normal using product d
    return v
}

// helper, calc dot product for two vectors
function dot(v1, v2) {
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y
}
```

Then you need a hit-test to trigger the reflection. When hit, reflect the incoming vector on the normal which is 90° tangent to the pad.

A simple demo:

```js
function getNormal(a) {
  return {
    x: Math.sin(a),
    y: -Math.cos(a)
  }
}

function reflect(n, v) {
  var d = 2 * dot(v, n);
  v.x -= d * n.x;
  v.y -= d * n.y;
  return v
}

function dot(v1, v2) {
  return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y
}

// --- for demo only ---
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    balls = [], padAngle = 0, angleDlt = 0.005;

function Ball() {         // a Ball object for demo (replace or use existing)
  var me = this;
  init();
  this.update = function() {
    if (this.posX < 0 || this.posX > 500 || this.posY < -4 || this.posY > 150) init();
    this.posX += this.x;
    this.posY += this.y;
    ctx.rect(this.posX - 2, this.posY - 2, 4, 4);
  };
  
  function init() {
    me.posX = Math.random() * 100 + 200;
    me.posY = -4;
    me.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
    me.y = 1;
    me.hit = false;
  }
}

// init some balls
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) balls.push(new Ball());

// animate demo
(function loop() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 150);
  
  // speeds up frames but preserves some accuracy
  for(var subframes = 0; subframes < 3; subframes++) {

    ctx.beginPath();
    
    // render pad
    padAngle += angleDlt;
    if (padAngle < -Math.PI * 0.2 || padAngle > Math.PI * 0.2) angleDlt = -angleDlt;
    drawPad(padAngle);
    
    // get normal
    var normal = getNormal(padAngle);
    
    // hit test using the pad's path - this is where we do the reflection
    for(var i = 0, ball; ball = balls[i++];) {
      if (!ball.hit && ctx.isPointInPath(ball.posX, ball.posY)) {
        ball.hit = true;
        reflect(normal, ball);
      }
    }

    // update balls
    for(var i = 0, ball; ball = balls[i++];) ball.update();
  }
  
  ctx.fill();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
})();

function drawPad(angle) {
  ctx.translate(250, 100);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.rect(-50, -3, 100, 6);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```html
<canvas width=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the extremely detailed response @Ken Fyrstenberg 
I think this is way over my head however, i'm guessing there isn't much of a simpler way either?

Comment: @joshuaaron it will be hard to find a solution not dealing with vectors. But if you study the linked demo you will see you don't have to deal too much with the math. Mostly you will deal with collision detection. You are already using vectors in your code so you are almost there....

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg I've copied and started studying the code and ill keep looking at the demo thanks.

Comment: function reflect(n, v) {
  var d = 2 * dot(v, n);
  v.x -= d * n.x;
  v.y -= d * n.y;
  return v
}
@KenFyrstenberg would you be able to shed some light on this section/What it is and why it works?

Comment: @joshuaaron (sorry, I have missed this comment) The dot product produces a "inner product" which tells you something about the relationship of angles between two vectors (the normal and the incoming vector in this case) or the cosine, i.e. a negative number would indicate opposite direction, 0 same direction etc. Multiplying it with 2 will cover the incoming delta + the new delta when reversed (if 1 it would almost "freeze"). Then that is used to negate and change the direction of the vector using the normal with the inner product.

Comment: @K3N haha this may be the latest reply I have received but I do appreciate you explaining this, thanks!