# Collision response - Body temporarily disappears while penetrating another body

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-physics

Based on [an answer to a previous question of mine about angular velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36885238/5083447), I've modified the given demo and implemented the seperating axis theorem (collision detection) along with rudimentary linear impulse resolution. ([here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/L7wwjqta/9/)). However, there's a tiny problem with the response.

If the bodies manage to penetrate each other (which does occasionally occur), the penetrating one temporarily disappears and then reappears again when they are no longer penetrating. But why?

```
let aVel = [a.dx, a.dy];
let bVel = [b.dx, b.dy];
const invA = a.static ? 0 : 1 / a.mass;
const invB = b.static ? 0 : 1 / b.mass;
const relativeVel = Sub(bVel, aVel);
const velAlongNorm = DotProduct(relativeVel, data.unit);

if (velAlongNorm > 0)
  return;

const cor = a.cor * b.cor;
let _j = -(1 + cor) * velAlongNorm;

_j /= invA + invB;

const impulse = ScalarMultiply(data.unit, _j);

aVel = Sub(aVel, ScalarMultiply(impulse, invA));

bVel = Add(bVel, ScalarMultiply(impulse, invB));

a.dx = aVel[0];
a.dy = aVel[1];

b.dx = bVel[0];
b.dy = bVel[1];

const percent = 0.2;
const slop = 0.01;
const correction = Math.max(data.overlap - slop, 0) / (invA + invB) * percent;
a.x -= invA * correction;
a.y -= invA * correction;
b.x += invB * correction;
b.y += invB * correction;
```

Note that `dx` and `dy` refer to the x and y components of the bodies' velocities, respectively, and `COR` refers to the coefficient of restitution. (bounciness) `invA` and `invB` are the inverse masses.

How do I fix the problem of the penetrating body disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out. I just forgot to translate the bodies by the minimum translation vector (MTV).

It's calculated by multiplying the collision normal by the overlap. (AKA penetration, depth, etc.)